# Get the container id where the gitlab job is executed

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

When I use gitlab with docker in the log of the job I can get this information:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on platform-docker-orc (2c06225e)
Using Docker executor with image registry:5000/local_image: ...
Using docker image sha256:db4434f2a9c3529af30397031df5bc1277f13882e0f6613a8c8f9c059645c04d for predefined container...
Pulling docker image registry:5000/local_image ...
Using docker image registry:5000/local_image ID=sha256:8d1cac8ae6371b01505e9cd3aaf654696cc144117a9c89dcd21cf4c0d9cfa709 for build container...
Running on runner-2c06225e-project-99-concurrent-0 via a96c0c765ce7...
```

How can I get the container id where the gitlab job is executed?

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain the container id by leveraging the labels on the container:

```
docker ps -q -f "label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.job.id=$CI_JOB_ID" -f "label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.type=build"
```

Specifying the `label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.type=build` filter will limit it to the build container. Else you will also get services container defined as part of your job.

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere? Finding it hard to believe it isn't exposed in a variable similar to `$CI_JOB_ID`.. can't find anything, though.

Comment: I haven't found this documented, but you can just checkout the labels from running containers and see what's useful for your use case.

Comment: I ended up using your snippet which was the final piece of a 6 hour long nightmare around container networking on my CI server... so thanks! :)

Comment: Just a quick note since I found myself here again -- the above filter will catch any services you also have specified in gitlab. I had to add another filter: `-f "label=com.gitlab.gitlab-runner.type=build"`

Comment: Thanks, that's great, I'll edit the answer accordingly.